# Is it possible to pass props outside of components return?

Tags: reactjs

I am a newbie to React and I am trying to make this work but I'm lost.
So I want to make a little app, where you can submit some issues, (later you can log in) and then see the issues listed. Like a to-do app.
I have App.js and two components, Submit.js and Issue.js.

My problem is that I want to pass my issueList from Submit.js to Issue.js but when I do it with  it seem like it renders the whole Issue.js component too causing some bugs.

Can i pass that list somehow to Issue without rendering so I return my data in Issue.js only?

Or I am messing the whole thing up and I should look for a different approach?

Thank you, please see my code below:

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Submit from './components/Submit';

function App(props) {

  const [issues, setIssues] = useState(props.issues);
  const [replies, setReplies] = useState(props.issues);
  const [isAdmin, setAdmin] = useState(false);

    /*function replying(reply) {
      const newReply = {reply: reply};
      setReplies([...replies, newReply]);
    }*/

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button type='button' onClick={() => setAdmin(true)}>
        Login
      </button>
      <button type='button' onClick={() => setAdmin(false)}>
        Logout
      </button>
      <Submit />
      {/* currently submit renders issue list too */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Submit.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import Issue from "./Issue";

function Submit(props) {

    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const [desc, setDesc] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [isSubmitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false);
    const [issues, setIssues] = useState(props.issues);
    const [replies, setReplies] = useState(props.issues);
    const [isAdmin, setAdmin] = useState(false);

    const issueList = issues.map(issue => (
        <Issue
            name={issue.name}
            desc={issue.desc}
            email={issue.email}
            reply={issue.reply}
            id={issue.id}
            key={issue.id}
            deleteIssue={deleteIssue}
        />
    ));

    function submitting(name, desc, email) {
        const newSubmit = { name: name, desc: desc, email: email, id: "issue-" + nanoid() };
        setIssues([...issues, newSubmit]);
    }

    function replying(reply) {
        const newReply = { reply: reply };
        setReplies([...replies, newReply]);
    }

    function deleteIssue(id) {
        const remainingIssues = issues.filter((issue) => id !== issue.id);
        setIssues(remainingIssues);
    }

    function handleChange(e) {
        setTitle(e.target.value);
    }

    function handleChangeDesc(e) {
        setDesc(e.target.value);
    }

    function handleChangeEmail(e) {
        setEmail(e.target.value);
    }

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        submitting(title, desc, email);
        setTitle("");
        setDesc("");
        setEmail("");
    }

    const startingTemplate = (
        <form>
            <h1>Facility ticketing</h1>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => setSubmitting(true)}>
                Report an issue
            </button>
        </form>
    );

    const submittingTemplate = (
        <div>
            <h1>Facility ticketing</h1>
            <h2>Report an issue</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>Title</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    id="new-issue"
                    className="new-issue classname"
                    name="text"
                    autoComplete="off"
                    value={title}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label>Description</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    id="new-issue-desc"
                    className="new-issue-desc classname"
                    name="desc"
                    autoComplete="off"
                    value={desc}
                    onChange={handleChangeDesc}
                />
                <h3>Attach a picture</h3>
                <input type="file" />
                <label>E-mail</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={handleChangeEmail}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <button type="submit">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );

    return (
        <div>
            {isSubmitting ? submittingTemplate : startingTemplate}
            <Issue issueList={issueList}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Submit;
```

Issue.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Issue(props) {

    const [reply, setReply] = useState(false);
    const [repMsg, setRepMsg] = useState("");

    function handleChange(e) {
        setRepMsg(e.target.value);
    }

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        setRepMsg("");
    }

    return (
        <div className="">
            <h3>Pending issues (3)</h3>
            <label className="" htmlFor={props.id}>
                <li>{props.name}</li>
                <li>{props.desc}</li>
                <li>{props.email}</li>
                <li>{props.id}</li>
                <button type="button" onClick={() => props.deleteIssue(props.id)}>
                    Delete
                </button>
                <button type="button" onClick={() => setReply(true)}>
                    Reply
                </button>
                <div style={{ visibility: reply ? "visible" : "hidden" }}>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <label>
                            <input
                                value={repMsg}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                        </label>
                        <button>
                            Send reply
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div>
                    {props.issueList}{ /* without this i cant submit */}
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Issue;
```

Comment: `Can i pass that list somehow to Issue without rendering so I return my data in Issue.js only?` - no.  Let's fix the issue with this list instead `causing some bugs` what bugs?

Comment: There are several issues with your components. Together with missing basic knowledge of how React works internally. First - every change of component props triggers re-render - that the answer to one of your question. The second is - anything that needs to trigger re-render of the component should be stored in `state`, anything that does not, should be in refs (`useRef` hook -> msg in your issue for example).